# Accoure Error 500 when i use HttpClient of android?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, web-services, webservice-client

I have below code and in this code i am using from `HttpClient` for connect to `webservice .Net` but when i using this, i get `Error 500` from here `Log.i("OK", Integer.toString(code));` but i need that when i get `200` i `login` to `webSite` and etc..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost methodPost = new HttpPost("http://online.test.com/MobileWebService/Related.asmx/Login");
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(methodPost);
                    int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    Log.i("OK", Integer.toString(code));
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Notice 1 : `..../Login` is a method in `webService` for `login`. It `get 4 parameters` .
Notice 2 : As the first step i should be sure that it is connected successfully (I mean I should get the "200") and then `Login` to webSite.

I don't like use `KSOAP` .

And below is my `webService .Net`:

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public int Login(string username, string pass, string device, int? security)
        {
            var ret = -3;
            try
            {
                var bs = new BaseMaster();
                if (!bs.securityRequest(10))
                {
                    return -10;
                }
                bs.setLogMobileVisit();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pass) || security == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
                {
                    ret = -2;
                }
                else if (security != 128110)
                {
                    ret = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    var user = GetUserByName(username);
                    var p = Hash.MD5(pass);
                    if (user != null && user.Hidden == false && user.Password == Hash.MD5(pass))
                    {
                        if (user.Firstname != device)
                        {
                            return -4;
                        }
                        var u = new UserDB();
                        u.LastLogDate = DateTime.Now;
                        u.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                        u.UserID = user.UserID;
                        Makarem_Facade.MakaremFL.UpdateMobileUserDB(u);
                        ret = (int)user.UserID;
                        var pl = new PermissionDBList();
                        Security.Login(user,false,pl);
                        StartSession(user);
                    }
                    else if (user.Hidden == true)
                    {
                        ret = 0;
                    }
                    else if (user == null)
                    {
                        ret = -3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ret = -5;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                ret = -6;           
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe server crash or call with wrong parameter

Comment: 500 is an internal serer error. Lookk at the server logfiles to find out what is wrong.

Comment: My needs work with ksoap without error but with HttpClient get me this error.